# Read xlsx stored on sharepoint location with openpyxl in python?

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, openpyxl

quick one.

I have XLSX file located on sharepoint drive and cannot open it using openpyxl in python, it works well if it is stored on my local drive.

I tried this.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('https://content.potatocompany.com/workspaces/PotatoTeam/Shared Documents/XYZ errors/XYZ Errors_Confirm.xlsx')
```

Throws up this exception:

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, use_iterators, keep_vba, guess_types, data_only)
    123     except (BadZipfile, RuntimeError, IOError, ValueError):
    124         e = exc_info()[1]
--> 125         raise InvalidFileException(unicode(e))
    126     wb = Workbook(guess_types=guess_types, data_only=data_only)
    127 

InvalidFileException: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'https://...
```

Am I missing something?
I need to read the content of one of the sheets in python.

---

EDIT:

Using crussell's advice, I receive **401 UNAUTHORIZED**:

```
import requests
import urllib
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

file = "https://content.potatocompany.com/workspaces/PotatoTeam/Shared Documents/XYZ errors/XYZ Errors_Confirm.xlsx"

username = 'PotatoUser'
password = 'PotatoPassword'

resp=requests.get(file, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
print(resp.content)
```

Seems like sharepoint and requests are not compatible, with both Digest Authentication and Basic Authentication
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to load directly from a web-address, try using urllib.

```
import urllib
file = "https://content.potatocompany.com/workspaces/PotatoTeam/Shared Documents/XYZ errors/XYZ Errors_Confirm.xlsx"
urllib.urlretrieve(file,"test.xlsx")
```

From further research, [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/) may be preferred over urllib. Try this:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
file = "https://content.potatocompany.com/workspaces/PotatoTeam/Shared Documents/XYZ errors/XYZ Errors_Confirm.xlsx"
        
username = 'myUsername'
password = 'myPassword'
        
resp=requests.get(file, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
output = open('test.xlsx', 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()
```

To get requests installed:

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: One forward slash throws this exception: URLError: <urlopen error no host given>

Comment: Thanks crussell, this seems to be right direction for me, now need to fight with authentication request while accessing the file. IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized' ...

Comment: Is the file encrpyted?

Comment: The web server seems to be expecting some authentication credentials, do you have a username and password for the website?

Comment: Yes i do have credentials and the file is not encrypted

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions crussell, It seems like there is authentication issues which cannot be handled by **requests**. Will keep looking for another method.

Comment: Instead of basic auth since this is internal sharepoint, I used this instead - 

from requests_negotiate_sspi
import HttpNegotiateAuth resp=requests.get(file, auth=HttpNegotiateAuth())

Answer (score 0):

You probably first need to download it first rather than opening it directly. The following approach should work:

```
import urllib2
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import StringIO

data = urllib2.urlopen("https://content.potatocompany.com/workspaces/PotatoTeam/Shared Documents/XYZ errors/XYZ Errors_Confirm.xlsx")
xlsx = data.read()
wb = load_workbook(StringIO.StringIO(xlsx))
```

Python's `StringIO` could be used to make the downloaded data appear as a file interface.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your suggestion, however I get :   560 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: I can open it in a browser,  otherwise I get this exception: HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Comment: Are you going through a proxy?

Comment: No, it supposed to be internal sharepoint location with web interface.

Comment: Apart from the headaches of logging into Sharepoint I don't think openpyxl supports the buffer interface. It's restricted to locally accessible files for reasons of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If the SP is internal, it might work by removing "https:" in the name you put in the `load_workbook()`.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
file = '//content.potatocompany.com/workspaces/PotatoTeam/Shared Documents/XYZ errors/XYZ Errors_Confirm.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(file)
```

without authentication if your account at work is directly connected to SP. Otherwise, at my work, we use NTML authentification, that you can do by using `HttpNtlmAuth` from the library `request_ntml`.

Let me know if it works or if you are still interested by this issue, I could give you example with `request_ntml`

Comment: I would be interested in seeing an example with request_ntml, please.

Comment: I have no issues opening the spreadsheet from SharePoint in a web browser, but trying to do so from a python script is giving me a 403 forbidden error. What am I missing?

`import requests_ntlm
import requests
file = "https://ourcompany.sharepoint.com/abcd/5UJJPA3D/FILE"
u=r"domain\username"
p="password"
resp = requests.get(file, auth=requests_ntlm.HttpNtlmAuth(u,p))
print(resp.content)
b'403 FORBIDDEN'`

Comment: @Calab Hi, unfortunately, I'm not at the same work anymore and I had to leave my scripts so I can't answer your question. sorry