# Download or Read Excel file from Organization SharePoint using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am trying to read the excel file that I stored in Sharepoint. But I wasn't able to. I have referred to most of the existing articles but that didn't solve my issue.

Code I referenced From: [How to read SharePoint Online (Office365) Excel files in Python with Work or School Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424045/how-to-read-sharepoint-online-office365-excel-files-in-python-with-work-or-sch)

[Read xlsx stored on sharepoint location with openpyxl in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203552/read-xlsx-stored-on-sharepoint-location-with-openpyxl-in-python)

But no luck.

```
import io
import json
import pandas as pd
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.runtime.http.request_options import RequestOptions
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
from io import BytesIO

username = '##########################'
password = '##########################'
site_url = "#######################################################"

ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(UserCredential(username, password))
request = RequestOptions("{0}/_api/web/".format(site_url))
response = ctx.execute_request_direct(request)
json_data = json.loads(response.content)
```

Error I am getting : [image]

Comment: I tried to do this a while ago and just ended up "Syncing" the sharepoint folder with my machine locally, its much easier to read and write to this way.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you. Once you download the file you can read it as per its respective file format.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password)   
ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
response = File.open_binary(ctx, "/Shared Documents/User Guide.docx")
with open("./User Guide.docx", "wb") as local_file:
    local_file.write(response.content)
```